# How to insert `null` values to database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, jpa, null

Please have a look at the below code.

```
 String textName=request.getParameter("textName");
 String textadr1=request.getParameter("textadr1");
 String textadr2=request.getParameter("textadr2");
 String textcntry=request.getParameter("textcntry");
 String textregNo=request.getParameter("textregNo");

     AgentContact agentContact=new AgentContact();
     AgentContact agentContact2=new AgentContact();
     Agent agent=new Agent();

     agent.setName(textName);
     agent.setRegistrationNumber(textregNo);
     agent.setDateOfDealStart(textDateDealing);
     agent.setRegistrationDate(textregDate);

     session.save(agent);  
     session.save(agentContact);  
     session.save(agentContact2);          
     session.getTransaction().commit();
```

In the above code, we get the values from a form, that is why `request.getParameter()` is used. However, user may or may not fill some fields like name, so the `txtName` will be empty.

However when this code is executed, I noticed Hibernate added "empty" string to these non specified Strings, instead of entering `null`. How can I set the code so it enters `null` values when the text are actually empty?

Comment: does your data field have a default?  is it nullable?

Comment: @djb: It is nullable, yes. No default values, which means if you didn't enter anything it will be `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Hiberate issue.

See here:

[Are empty fields in form of JSP null or ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136232/are-empty-fields-in-form-of-jsp-null-or)

You simply need to check for an empty String and act accordingly:

agent.setName(textName.equals("") ? null : textName);

The above is a somewhat simplistic solution however: what if the user enters a space? You can use methods of Apache Commons StringUtils for more robust checking:

e.g.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)

agent.setName(StringUtils.isBlank(textName) ? null : textName);

Comment: +1, or simply StringUtils.trimToNull: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.433

Comment: ah yeah that makes sense.  the request params will come in as "", not null.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.